# difference between type alias and generic class in scala

Tags: scala

There are two ways to define a class with type parameters:

```
trait A { type T ; def foo(i:T) = print(i) }
class B extends A { type T = Int }
```

or

```
trait A[T] { def foo(i:T) = print(i) }
class B extends A[Int] {}
```

What's the difference and are they exactly same for scala compiler?
Which way is better (in which cases)?

Comment: The first one is a path-dependent type, the second one is a type parameter; two very different things. Usually, you want the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former isn't [just] a type alias, it's a path dependent type. Meaning the type of `T` in enclosed in an instance of `A`.

With a path dependent type, it's not possible to know the type of `T` given an instance of `A` (only if you know the subtype). Consider

```
val a: A = ???
a.foo(???)
```

With the generic type, we do (typically) know the type of `T` without knowing the subtype of `A`. Consider

```
val a: A[Int] = ???
a.foo(5)
```

On the other hand, with path dependent types you can do

```
trait A { type T; def foo(s:String): T }
class B extends A { type T = Int; def foo(s: String) = s.length }

def fun(a: A): A#T = a.foo("hello")
val out: Int = fun(new B()) // 5
```

We can have the output type of `fun` depend on the parameter being passed, but not need to add a generic parameter.